# How to add scrollbar to Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Python 3.5.2

This is the bases of my code:

```
from tkinter import *
w = Tk()
w.geometry("650x600")

#A very large amount of labels here. Too many to be able to see them all.

w.mainloop()
```

How would I add a scrollbar to this to be able to go to the bottom of my window?
I havn't found any answers online specific to this case. They all deal with either listboxes, frames or canvases. This is only the Tkinter window. And no, I cannot edit my code to work with a canvas or anything.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "labels"? Do you mean "lines of text" or "Label widgets"?

Comment: You cannot add a scrollbar directly to a window. The most commn solution is to use a canvas and a frame.

Comment: Yea i meant label widgets. And I just put everything in a text box and put a scrollbar on that. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, using a text widget is another common way, especially if you have just a vertical stack of widgets.

Answer (score 1):

You may take this for example and try it out:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )

w = Label(root, text="Label: ")#some label

mylist = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
for line in range(100):
   mylist.insert(END, w.cget("text") + str(line))

mylist.pack( side = LEFT, fill = BOTH )
scrollbar.config( command = mylist.yview )

mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]